# Facebook Rate Limit, what counts as an active user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website that makes a call to Facebook to see how many times certain links have been shared but i'm wondering about the Rate Limit. I'm trying to estimate the rate limit my site has, according to the official documentation the rate limit is calculated like this:

> The number of users for your app is calculated as the average number
>   of daily active users plus today's new logins as an estimated value.
>   Apps with a larger number of users may have more accurate rate
>   limiting than apps with a smaller number of users. Apps with a very
>   small number of users may have rate limit issues.

But what counts as an active user? everyone that makes a call to the API through my site/app? everyone that visits the site/app and is logged in to Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Users are users who are interacting with your APP (what means that they are making some kind of API calls) It doesn't matter if they are logged into FB when they are using an active access token.